# How can this php code be made vulnerable to sql injection and cross site scripting attacks?

Tags: php, sql, xss

Im currently learning about software security vulnerabilities, specifically SQL injection and XSS attacks. Ive been given a task to make a secure application vulnerable but i have no prior background on coding PHP.

From my understanding, the application could be made vulnerable if the PDO is removed but i have no specific solution for this. Can anyone provide an answer? Im desperate

Registration

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{
$fname=$_POST['fullname'];
$email=$_POST['emailid']; 
$mobile=$_POST['mobileno'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']); 
$sql="INSERT INTO  tblusers(FullName,EmailId,ContactNo,Password) VALUES(:fname,:email,:mobile,:password)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':fname',$fname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':mobile',$mobile,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
echo "<script>alert('Registration successfull. Now you can login');</script>";
}
else 
{
echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong. Please try again');</script>";
}
}

?>
```

Login

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$sql ="SELECT EmailId,Password,FullName FROM tblusers WHERE EmailId=:email and Password=:password";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
$_SESSION['login']=$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['fname']=$results->FullName;
$currentpage=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '$currentpage'; </script>";
} else{

  echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details');</script>";

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Remove the prepared statement. It's already vulnerable

Comment: one general vulnerability: you're using md5 - which has been deemed insecure for **over a decade** now.

Answer (score 0):

For sql injection, you can remove the `bindParam` lines and write something like the following instead in say Login:

```
$sql ="SELECT EmailId,Password,FullName FROM tblusers WHERE EmailId='$email' and Password='$password'";
```

As the parameters would now be passed in to sql with string concatenation, this would make it vulnerable to sql injection on both the email amd password variables.

For XSS, you would have to output user input without encoding. For example in login, you could write the received username in the response like this:

```
echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details for $email');</script>";
```

That way the email field would be easily exploitable.

Note that these are just examples, the same can be achieved in countless different ways.